# Calculate the shape - Keras

Tags: python, keras

How to calculate the shape of weights and bias for these two layers in keras -

`x1 = Conv1D(256, 3, padding='same', activation="relu")(x1)`

`x2 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding="same", activation="relu")(x2)`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the weights and bias shape can be checked by calling a get_weights method on layer and checking a shape of its return values. the method returns weights, bias in list.

```
import tensorflow as tf 
layer = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(256, 3, padding='same', activation="relu")
x1 = layer(x1)
weights, bias = layer.get_weights()
print(weights.shape)
print(bias.shape)
```

similarly, you can also get wieghts and bias shape from Conv2D layer.